# In Abp.io LeptopXLite theme on Angular, how to make the sidebar closed by default?

Tags: angular, abp

[image]

The Sidebar is `open` by default, is there a way to change its behavior and make it `closed` by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here's the solution

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { LayoutService } from '@volo/ngx-lepton-x.core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <abp-loader-bar></abp-loader-bar>
    <abp-dynamic-layout></abp-dynamic-layout>
    <abp-gdpr-cookie-consent></abp-gdpr-cookie-consent>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  protected readonly layoutService = inject(LayoutService);
  constructor() {
    this.layoutService.addClass('hover-trigger')
  }
}
```

Comment: It works.
Maybe it's best if it is exposed as a configuration parameter in future updates.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
This is the solution provided by the ABP team:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77606148/655605

---

For what it's worth, I made it work with a walkaround. I triggered the click event on the button. Here is the code for your reference:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    
    const element = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.menu-collapse-icon');

    if (element) {
      element.click();
    }
  }

}
```